# Why is the WPF Border’s "Border" visible in design mode, but not in the application?

Tags: wpf

[image]

The designer shows a black border around the red background, but the actual application only shows the red background. What gives? How to force the black border to be visible?

Here’s the XAML for this window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        MinWidth="400" MinHeight="300"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <DockPanel Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="A button"
                Padding="8,2" Margin="8" />
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="10" BorderBrush="Black"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Red" />
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="A button"
                Padding="8,2" Margin="8" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is that the border, or is it just a line round the control so you can there's something on the design surface?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson For a moment there I thought you had just explained what happened, but actually... no, that is the border: http://i.imgur.com/ilQb0.png

Comment: Oh well, the answer can't always be simple. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the default thickness of the border during runtime is 0 - possibly because of an inherited style in the application resource dictionary. Default styles inherited from a global resource dictionary often don't show up during design time.

Try explicitly setting the `BorderThickness="1"`

Comment: This happens even in a blank project... guess it’s another WPF thing I’ll have to put up with... :)

Comment: As a WPF UI developer, I've completely given up on using the designer and rely entirely on my mind's eye and [SNOOP](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the border is showing up in Design Mode but you can make it show up in the application by adding an explicit thickness

```
<Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="10" BorderBrush="Black"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
```

Comment: Snap to device pixels worked for me, I think it was rendering over a half pixex causeing my border to be half the saturation.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Gray4}"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
```

Replace value of property "Color", using hex:

```
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD33B3B"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
```